# How to install synaptics clickpad patch?

Tags: package-management, touchpad, dpkg, synaptics

I'm affected by  [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/932947), which means my [ClickPad](http://www.synaptics.com/solutions/products/clickpad) is not working properly. The bug-description says, there are patches for this, which can be found [here.](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~cndougla/xf86-input-synaptics/log/?h=clickpad-v2) But when I download the newest version of this, I get an archive with directories and files and I have no idea on how to install this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions are here: http://www.theorangenotebook.com/2012/02/call-for-testing-clickpad.html

Answer (score 1):

I made a script (based on post linked by sendmoreinfo) to solve this bug.

You can find it here: https://github.com/leodido/elantech-clickpad-fix

Hope to be helpful.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.